# Can I access a variable within a heredoc in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, heredoc

If I have a method

```
  def some_method p = {}
    string = <<-MY_TERMINATOR
      Example text blah blah
      lorem ipsum something or another
    MY_TERMINATOR
  end
```

how can I access the variable p[:name] from within the heredoc?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can interpolate just like in normal strings

```
<<-TERMINATOR
  Example #{p[:name]} blah blah blah
TERMINATOR
```